# Private method interception using byte-buddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

How can I Intercept private methods using byte-buddy? I am able to intercept all the public methods using Advice but when I submit private method signature for interception it is not intercepted?

Comment: Could you share some code on how you are using advice?

Comment: AgentBuilder agentBuilder = new AgentBuilder.Default()
                     .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.REDEFINITION)
                     .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REDEFINE);


agentBuilder = agentBuilder
                     .type(ElementMatchers.hasSuperType(named(instrumentedClassName)))
                     .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                             .include(cl.currentClassLoader()) // 
                             .advice(matchAnyMethodIn(instrumentedMethods), myAdvice.class.getName())
                     );

Comment: Hi Rafael, this is how I am using advice, this is similar to https://github.com/fstab/promagent/blob/master/promagent-framework/promagent-internal/src/main/java/io/promagent/internal/Promagent.java

Answer (score -1):

My mistake, there is explicit call element matchers to match only public, my bad I overlooked it, I am able to intercept the public and private methods now.